# One liner. Plotting a histogram using a method from class instances in a list

Tags: python, list, class, lambda, python-3.5

I have just learned to use pythonic lambda. 
Why this works:

```
print(max(my_firms, key=lambda firm: firm.num_members()))
```

But this will not:

```
plt.hist(my_firms, key=lambda firm: firm.num_members())
```

That is. I have a list, my_firms, that contains class instances, firm, that have a method num.members(). I want to do a histogram with the quantity of members of all firms in my_firms.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every method will accept a `key` argument.  In fact, *most* don't.  I suspect that matplotlib's `hist` function is one that doesn't.

In this case, you'll probably want to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to transform the `firm` objects into numbers of members:

```
plt.hist([f.num_members() for f in my_firms])
```

In other places, you'll probably use a [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/748858) instead, but IIRC, `plt.hist` expects an array-like object and generators don't quite fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `plt.hist` doesn't take any keyword arguments called `key`. Check the documentation.

As for your plot, you can are probably achieve what you are looking for with a list comprehension like this:

```
plt.hist([f.num_members() for f in my_firms])
```